# How does Snowflake calculate its HASH() output?

Tags: hash, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Take a look at this query

```
select 
    hash( col1, col2 ) as a,
    col1||col2 as b, -- just taking a guess as to how hash can take multiple values
    hash( b ) as c 
from table_name
```

The result for **a** and **c** are different.

So, my question is: how does Snowflake calculate the hash when there are many fields like in **a**? Is it concatinating the fields first, and then signing that result of that?

Thank you

Comment: As it is described as a proprietary function, I doubt that Snowflake has/will release details for how HASH is implemented

Comment: @NickW could you point me to where the docs say that?

Comment: It’s the first line of the “note” in the documentation for the function

Answer (score 0):

More to NickW's point that [HASH](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/hash.html) is proprietary

> HASH is a proprietary function that accepts a variable number of input expressions of arbitrary types and returns a signed value. It is not a cryptographic hash function and should not be used as such.

I assume the core of the problem you are trying to achieve, is to "make a value in another system, and be able to compare these "safely", of which concatenating strings together, seems very dangerous, as the number and length of each string is a property of those strings.

The [usage notes](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/hash.html#usage-notes) section has some good hints:

> Any two values of type NUMBER that compare equally will hash to the same hash value, even if the respective types have different precision and/or scale.

this implies that things are converted to this form.. but it also notes on convertion:

> Note that this guarantee does not apply to other combinations of types, even if implicit conversions exist between the types.

What really would help is for you to describe, what you want to happen for you, then if "knowing how HASH works" is the best path to that end, OR not as I would suggest, would be more answerable.

Aka, this answer is a long form question, suggesting this question needs to be reworked.

Comment: Great response. I was just trying to understand what are Snowflake's steps in generating the HASH value - which is an int. Does it concatenate first? etc